# type mismatch; found : Object required: play.api.mvc.Result

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

At `getOrElse` in the code that follows, I'm getting the following error:

> `type mismatch; found : Object required: play.api.mvc.Result`

What is wrong? I'm usinging playframework2.2

```
def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) =
        Results.BadRequest(Json.obj("error" -> "Invalid signature"))

def withUserSigner(f: User => Request[Map[String, Seq[String]]] => Result) = Action(BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded) {
        request =>
            val userOpt = request.body.get(SRT_ACCESS_KEY).flatMap { email =>
                DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
                    User.findByEmail(email.mkString).flatMap { user =>
                        getSigner(request.method, request.path, request.body, user)
                    }
                }
            }

            userOpt.map { user =>
                Action(BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded) { request => f(user)(request) }(request)
            }.getOrElse {  *//got error in this line   "type mismatch; found : Object required: play.api.mvc.Result"*
               onUnauthorized(request)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this snippet:

```
userOpt.map { user =>
  Action(BodyParsers.parse.urlFormEncoded) { request => f(user)(request) }(request)
}.getOrElse {  
  onUnauthorized(request)
}
```

In your `map` you're calling `Action` which just returns an `Action`, not a `Result`.  The type returned by `getOrElse` is an object because it's the common ancestor of both `Result` and `Action`.

Since you have both the user and request required to invoke `f`, you should just do this:

```
userOpt.map { user =>
  f(user)(request)
}.getOrElse {  
  onUnauthorized(request)
}
```